# In SSRS, how to evaluate expression stored in a database table in reprort at runtime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 R2. 
Expressions (specifically date expressions) are stored in a database table.
I fetch that expressions using stored procedure and display it in texbox.
Now the problem is textbox is not evaluating that expression at runtime. Instead it display expression as is (in string. like "Today()" instead of "1/7/2003").

So, in short, i want a functionality as given by Eval() function in VBScript.
So, if anybody tried this please give me sollution or suggestion.

Let me know if any confusion.

Comment: To clarify: is an expression being stored in the database e.g. "Today"?

Comment: Yes. Expression can be anything which is valid in report.

Comment: AFAIK there is no equivalent to VBScript's Eval() in .NET. Alternatives are: invent your own parser; use something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3445/Runtime-Compilation-A-NET-eval-statement and jump through the requisite hoops to get working with Reporting Services

Comment: Why dont you get the SP to return what you need?